# How does dimensions for placeholders work for tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

So suppose I have `x_train` and `y_train` where they are arrays and each element of that array a data point (in an array form)(so `x_train` would be in the form of `x_train[i][j]`). so `x_train[0]` represents 1st data point in the training set (in an array form) and suppose I want to create a simple regression

so I coded this

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[len(data[0]),None])
target = tf.placeholder(tf.flaot32, shape=[len(data[0]),None])

network = tf.layers.Dense(10, tf.keras.activations.relu)(input)
network = tf.layers.BatchNormalization()(network)

network = tf.layers.Dense(10,tf.keras.activations.relu)(network)
network = tf.layers.BatchNormalization()(network)

network = tf.layers.Dense(10,tf.keras.activations.linear)(network)

cost = tf.reduce_mean((target - network)**2)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
     for epoch in range(1000):
           _, val = sess.run([optimizer,cost], feed_dict={input: x_train, target: y_train})
           print(val)
```

But is this correct? I'm not sure if the dimensions for the placeholders even match. When I try to run this code,
I get the error message

```
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

So what I tried was to interchange the position of the dimensions' size for placeholders, so
the changed placeholders were

```
    input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,len(data[0])])
    target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,len(data[0])])
```

But with these, I then get the error message

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value dense/bias
 [[{{node dense/bias/read}}]]
```

Comment: You cannot have input dimensionality `None` if you want to use a `Dense` layer. That's what the first error is. To avoid the second error, run `tf.global_variables_initializer().run()` as the first line within `with tf.Session() as sess: ` context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the above issue by performing `np.expand_dims()` on `x_train` & `y_train` at `axis=0` and initializing batch_norm and network parameters with `sess.run(tf.global_variable_initializer())` before optimizing the model.

Note: The presence of `None` in the first dimension of the shape of placeholder is alright as it allows TensorFlow to train models when batch_size is unknown (the same is true even for other dimensions of placeholder's shape). The error is due to *mismatch* in input and placeholder dimensions. Your inputs (`x_train` & `y_train`) were probably one-dimensional tensors while the placeholders either needed two-dimensional ones or one-dimensional vectors reshaped to two-dimensions.

Please find my below implementation for the same and a `matplotlib` plot that verifies the implementation:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]]
x_train = data[0]
y_train = data[1]
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, 0)
y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, 0)

input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, len(data[0])])
target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, len(data[1])])

network = tf.layers.Dense(10, tf.keras.activations.relu)(input)
network = tf.layers.BatchNormalization()(network)

network = tf.layers.Dense(10,tf.keras.activations.relu)(network)
network = tf.layers.BatchNormalization()(network)

network = tf.layers.Dense(10,tf.keras.activations.linear)(network)

cost = tf.reduce_mean((target - network)**2)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

costs = []

with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
     for epoch in range(1000):
        _, val = sess.run([optimizer,cost], feed_dict={input: x_train, target: y_train})
        costs.append(val)
        print(val)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 8))
ax.plot(range(1000), costs)
ax.set_title("Costs vs epochs")
ax.set_xlabel("Epoch")
ax.set_ylabel("Avg. val. accuracy")
```

Here's the plot of costs vs epochs:

Costs vs Epochs
[image]

Additionally, to test the network on new data (say) `x_test = [[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]]`, you could use below code:

```
 y_pred = sess.run(network,feed_dict={input: x_test})
```

PS: Ensure you use the same Tensorflow Session `sess` created above to run the inference (unless you're not saving and loading the model checkpoint)